# 3.5mm relay pin spacing with a breadboard

Tags: breadboard, latching-relay

I purchased some Panasonic latching relays for my small project and just realized that it uses 3.5mm spacing between the pins. I can't seem to use it in a standard breadboard or perfboard. Is there a good way to mount it without ordering a custom PCB?

Comment: One way would be to solder some pieces of wire to the pins (like 10-15 mm long), so you get enough length to bend the pins to suit the 2.54 mm spacing.

Comment: Place it diagonally; 2.54 mm becomes 3.59mm diagonally and not too far off.

Comment: Or just simply drill holes to suit.

Answer (score 2):

For your small project on breadboard, you can make an adaptor board out of stripboard (Veroboard).

This can hold many relays at once. To make one:

- Use a small drill or stripboard cutter to cut holes/slots in between the 0.1" strips for the positions of your relay.
- Secure relay(s) to the board, such as (a) with a cable tie looped over a relay and over, or through holes in, the board, or (b) superglue.
- Solder link wires between the relay and strips.
- Put 0.1" header pins through the stripboard from the underside (strip side), held far enough off the strips to be soldered to them.

If you need a more compact arrangement, you could look at using Verowire board (individual square pads in 0.1" grid) and suitable current link wires.

I made a fair amount of stuff in this way.